# Animation. Expand div hight without setting directli it's height (angular app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, animation, transition

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/anastsiacrs/Lt7aP/1639/

[Please, run example in jsfiddle, stackoverflow's code does not run]

```js
function XController($scope) {
    $scope.model={isHidden:true};
}
```

```css
.open-div{
  background-color:red;
  //height:260px;
}
.hidden-div{
  background-color:green;
  //height:60px;
}
.transformable {
    -webkit-transition: 3000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: 3000ms linear;
    -o-transition: 3000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: 3000ms linear;
    transition: 3000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="XController">
<div ng-class="{'hidden-div' : model.isHidden, 'open-div' : !model.isHidden}" class="transformable">
  <input type="button" ng-click="model.isHidden=!model.isHidden" ng-show="model.isHidden" value="Open"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="model.isHidden=!model.isHidden" ng-hide="model.isHidden" value="Close"/>
  <p>{{isHidden}}  </p>
  <div ng-hide="model.isHidden"  >
     <div>Hello XXX</div>
     <p> Some content will be here </p>
     <p> Some content will be here </p>
     <p> Some content will be here </p>
     <p> Some content will be here </p>
     <p> Some content will be here </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

1. As you can see,  without explicit height animation doesn't apply for this property. What is the possible way to solve this issue. May be there are some library or link, that will help me.
2. If height is directly setted to element, there is another one issue wiht div content. It is apper before div is fully expanded.

some tips will be very pleased

Comment: for the 2, you can add dislplay:none css property

Comment: @BipBip for div content? until what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap collapse.js can be used here.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the CSS`height` to `min-height`? If the hidden `div` is bigger than the minimum height it will still expand. Should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, i tried. If min-heigt is used for both elements, animation is applied only on div close http://jsfiddle.net/anastsiacrs/1drry10r/

Comment: On your fiddle I gave the open class a min-height and the hidden a fixed height. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/1395510 Shows how to make the height transition so it doesn't just appear

Comment: Thx for link. According you advice with min height http://jsfiddle.net/anastsiacrs/1xucbjwp/ - it does not work. One of appropriate solution for me is animate padding http://jsfiddle.net/anastsiacrs/2zbxmbxw/1/ But it is still not what i want